# echo javascript function in php

Tags: javascript, php

I can not call the javascript function with the following javascript link. What is the problem here anyone can help me here please.

```
$buttonMessage = '

 <a class="drupalchat-profile-un drupalchat_cng" 
 href="javascript:void(0)"    
 onclick="javascript:chatWith('.$pUsername.','.$profile_uid.','.$UserAvatar.','.$onof.')">  
 </a>';
```

Comment: we need to see more of your code - show us `chatWith` method and more of your php code

Comment: @messerbill you don't need some more code. Because the problem is all `'` quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've probably some JS errors, and need to add single quotes around your values :

```
$buttonMessage = '

 <a class="drupalchat-profile-un drupalchat_cng" 
 href="javascript:void(0)"    
 onclick="javascript:chatWith(\''.$pUsername.'\',\''.$profile_uid.'\',\''.$UserAvatar.'\',\''.$onof.'\')">  
 </a>';
```